# Web Scraping com Rvest - Problema com raspagem dos dados (links principalmente)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Estou tentando fazer um Web Scraping do site da Web Of Science, mas esstou enfrentando problemas com a raspagem de links do site.

Minha intenção é raspar títulos dos artigos, links que direcionam para cada página do artigo dentro da Web of Science para que eu possa raspar outros dados como: resumo, palavras-chave, entre outros. E por fim fazer um looping para raspar essas informações até a última página da pesquisa.

Iniciei com o seguinte código:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link <- paste0("https://apps.webofknowledge.com/Search.do?", 
    "product=WOS&SID=5Bzr6AeuFKanEWXAFWh&search_mode=GeneralSearch&",
    "prID=45752f34-12a3-474b-8fcf-6b21a2196ed7")

page <- read_html(link)

titulo_artigo <- page %>%
  html_nodes(".snowplow-full-record value") %>%
  html_text()

links_dos_artigos <-page %>%
  html_nodes(".snowplow-full-record value") %>%
  html_attr("href")
```

Entretanto, `links_dos_artigos` retornam apenas valores NA e não os links que eu preciso

Agradeço se alguém puder ajudar.

Comment: Benvindo ao StackOverflow em Portugês! Dheynne, o link que passou é de um endereço sob login, então, precisa passar os parâmetros para acessar esta página. Não sei se ainda funciona, mas testou o package `wosr`?

Comment: Ainda não testei esse pacote wosr, irei dar uma olhada nele.
 Em relação ao link realmente ele tem acesso restrito, aqui consigo acessar pela internet da Instituição de Ensino Federal (acesso livre).

Vou dar uma olhada no pacote mencionado. Muito Obrigado, Daniel Kenaga!

Answer (score 0):

Estou com o mesmo problema mas o site não é restrito.

```
    html <- "https://www.fujioka.com.br/581992"

    LinkProduto <- read_html(html) %>% 
    html_node("body > main > section.vitrine > div.vitrine__wrapper > div > ul > li > article > div.productCard__info > a") %>% 
    html_attr("href")
```

Ele sempre retorna

```
    {xml_missing}
    <NA>
```

Tenho uma tabela com vários códigos de produtos e preciso pegar o link deles.

Consigo fazer usando RSelenium, mas demora muito. Quero fazer com rvest para ganhar tempo.